# 2016 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

Arqade's [fifth moderator election](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/election/5) has come to a close, the votes have been tallied, and the 2 new moderators are:

[image: Wipqozn] [image: Robotnik]

They'll be joining [the existing crew](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly — please thank them for volunteering, and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/election/5), or [view a summary report online](http://www.opavote.org/results/6487727256109056/0).

Comment: A very, very short summary report.

Comment: @badp: It's not often I can do a Meek STV in my head.

Comment: Just want to thank everyone for their support! I won't disappoint you!

Comment: Some overkill by the two winners! :)
|

Comment: Congratulations to the new mods! And also thankyou to the other candidates, your hard work on the site hasn't gone unnoticed, keep it up!

Answer (score 18):

Congrats to New mod **Wipqzon** and **Robotnik**. Hope you will give your best as other mods are giving. And thank you for other people too who tried for mod. All the best for future and again thank you for supporting :)

Comment: Thanks Leo! We will I'm sure :)

Comment: And that's why we believe in mod :)